# Datetimepicker calendar to display Mon-Sun instead of Sun-Sat

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

My calendar looks like this now:

[image]

I want my calendar to display the days Mon-Sun instead. What do i have to add to my code?

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"</script>

moment.lang('en', {
  week : {
    dow : 1 // Monday is the first day of the week
  }
});

$('#weekFilter').datetimepicker({
  format:'DD-MM-YYYY',
});
```

Comment: You are importing two diffent versions of momentjs, just use only one. Note that [`moment.lang`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/) was deprecated in 2.8.1, use `moment.locale` instead. In your code sample there is a typo, a `>` is missing in last `<script>`

Comment: Ah i see. Yes changed it to moment.locale() and got rid of the bottom src and replaced moment v2.10.6 to v2.17.1